# iText Add values to placeholders in PDF cover page dynamically

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, itext

I have the following cover page. I need to add values for **Licensee**, **date** and fill in the box with another text given. How can this be done using iText. Any help is appreciated.[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First you need to create a form that will act as a template for all your license document. Section 5.3.5 of [Chapter 6 of "iText in Action"](https://manning-content.s3.amazonaws.com/download/d/3645210-8560-4e6d-9b03-3f9aca1921a5/samplechapter6.pdf) (a chapter that can be downloaded for free) explains how to create such a form using OpenOffice, but there are many alternative ways to do this. I created such a form using Adobe Acrobat: [CertificateOfExcellence.pdf](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext/sandbox/raw/master/resources/pdfs/CertificateOfExcellence.pdf)

[image]

I highlighted the fields so that you can see where I've added them. There are four:

- *course:* the name of the course in 14pt Helvetica, with centered alignment
- *name:* the name of the student in Helvetica, left alignment
- *date:* the date of the course in Helvetica, left alignment
- *description of the course:* the name of the student in Helvetica, left alignment with the multi-line flag on.

Now I can easily fill out the form (see [FillForm](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/form-examples/filling-out-forms#1702-fillform.java)):

```
public void manipulatePdf(String src, String dest) throws DocumentException, IOException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();
    form.setField("course", "Copying and Pasting from StackOverflow");
    form.setField("name", "Some dude on StackOverflow");
    form.setField("date", "April 10, 2016");
    form.setField("description",
        "In this course, people consistently ignore the existing documentation completely. "
        + "They are encouraged to do no effort whatsoever, but instead post their questions "
        + "on StackOverflow. It would be a mistake to refer to people completing this course "
        + "as developers. A better designation for them would be copy/paste artist. "
        + "Only in very rare cases do these people know what they are actually doing. "
        + "Not a single student has ever learned anything substantial during this course.");
    stamper.setFormFlattening(true);
    stamper.close();
}
```

The resulting PDF looks like this: [certificate.pdf](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext/sandbox/raw/master/cmpfiles/acroforms/cmp_certificate.pdf)

[image]

As you can see, the code is very simple. All of this is very well documented for those who take the time to read the documentation. Maybe you can also take a look at the section entitled [Interactive forms](http://developers.itextpdf.com/faq/category/interactive-forms) on the [official web site](http://developers.itextpdf.com/).

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was exactly what I wanted to do. :)